# Angular6 : PrimeNg datatable: nova-light theme not being activated

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular 6 app with the latest version of PrimeNG (6.1.4) and using a simple datatable.
I want to use the nova-light theme but this is not working, the table structure is created but no theming.
I have the following lines im my styles.scss:

```
@import url("~primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css");
```

However: when I change to the now deprecated Omega theme then I get the datatable nicely with theming. Using the following lines

```
@import url("~primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");
@import url("~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css");
```

So, the only difference is switching from nova-light to omega. Which confuses me, because Omega is a deprecated theme.
How can I get the now recommended nova-light working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem: the datatable component is deprecated too, one should use the new table (TurboTable) component, and that one works fine with the nova-light theme....